# have no idea why for loop won't print, have checked so many times that the format is right

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int v;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("works\n");

    for(v= 0; v>10; v++){
        printf("%d", v);
        printf("|\n|\n|\n|\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

hello, what's wrong? this loop won't print.
i genuinely don't know why it won't print. my god why won't stackoverflow let me post my question. this is part of a larger main function. didn't work there so i tried in a separate script, still didn't work. googled and looked at my textbook for the for loop format, it's all spot on. i don't know why it won't work

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
for(v= 0; v>10; v++){
          ^^^
```

to

```
for(v= 0; v < 10; v++){
```

This condition `v>10` is equal to false when v has initial value 0.

Comment: wow thanks. i'm so sorry for asking stupid questions, haven't slept and it's due in 3 hours

Comment: @hwang hyungchae it happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(v= 0; v<10; v++){
```

since v is not bigger than 10, the for loop won't even  be excecuted